# Operações com Data Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de saber como fazer cálculos com datas no Mysql.

Tabela:

```
ID | DataValidade (DATETIME)
1  | 2017-01-01 00:00:00
2  | 2017-05-01 00:00:00
3  | 2016-06-01 00:00:00
```

Preciso retornar os registros cujo a data de validade é 30 dias da data de hoje.
Preciso retornar os registros cujo a data de validade é entre períodos.

Fiz

```
SELECT * FROM tabela where DATE_SUB(DataValidade, 30)
```

mas está retornando erro `#1064`

Alguém pode me ajudar ou mandar links onde tenha exemplos bons que posso estudar a respeito de operações com datas mysql?

Comment: 1064 é erro de sintaxe, desconfio que esteja faltando a **unidade**, são 30 dias, 30 meses, 30 anos etc?

Comment: @rray, inicialmente são 30 dias, mas as operações podem variar de acordo com as opções, tipo 30 dias, meses e anos

Comment: vc precisa dizer para o MySQL de alguma forma aquele 30 são dias :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1064 é o sqlstate para erro de sintexa, no seu caso faltou a palavra chave `INTERVAL` seguida da unidade(segundos, minutos, dias etc), um exemplo funcional seria esse:

```
SELECT date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY ) #2016-05-09 12:32:23
```

As demais opçãoes de unidades estão na [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Essa consulta exibe os registros a 30 dias já vencidos:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE DataValidade <= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Para registros que vão vencer troque `data_sub()` por `date_add()` que adiciona dias(minutos segundos etc) em uma data

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE DataValidade <= DATE_add(now(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Comment: entendi, mas nesse caso como selecionaria os registros que irão vencer dentro de 30 dias? Tenho a data de Validade gravada no banco

Comment: @lelopes vc quer os registros com data para frente ou p trás?

Comment: data para frente.

Comment: @lelopes eu editei a pergunta, deu certo? então o certo é usar `date_add()`